# How to get the SQL-server login name of an integrated security account?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, logins

Let's say I'm a user in windows domain DC (DataCenter). 
My user-name is DC\Somebody
I'm in group DC\Developers
Now SQL-Server has the login group called DC\Developers, and with that, I can login on the server with integrated security.

I'm now trying to get the SQL-Server login (by which I mean DC\Developers), but I can't figure out how. All I can get is the username (DC\Somebody). 
But I want to get DC\Developers. 
How can I do that ?

This are the functions I tried so far, without success:

```
SELECT -- http://blog.sqlconcepts.co.nz/2011/07/who-am-i.html 
        ORIGINAL_LOGIN() AS OriginalLogin
       ,SUSER_SNAME() AS CurrentContext 
       ,SESSION_USER AS SessionUser 
       ,SYSTEM_USER AS SystemUser
       ,CURRENT_USER AS CurrentUser 
       ,user AS "WhichUserIsThat?"
       ,ORIGINAL_LOGIN() AS OriginalLogin 
       ,USER_NAME() AS UserName
```

Also, what happens if multiple groups are added as sql-server logins, and I'm a member of them all, and then I login with integrated security. Which login will it take ? It appears to be the alphabetically first ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To get the AD groups with exsting logins on the instance that your login `DC\Somebody` belongs to**

---

**xp_logininfo**

```
EXEC xp_logininfo 'DC\Somebody','all';
```

---

**sys.login_token**

```
SELECT DISTINCT lt.name 
FROM sys.login_token lt
INNER JOIN  sys.server_principals  sp
ON lt.principal_id = sp.principal_id AND  sp.type != 'R'
WHERE lt.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE type = 'R' AND name IS NOT NULL) 
AND sp.type != 'R';
```

**An example to validate this for other logins with impersonation**

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN ='DOMAIN\a-rvertongen';

SELECT DISTINCT lt.name 
FROM sys.login_token lt
INNER JOIN  sys.server_principals  sp
ON lt.principal_id = sp.principal_id
WHERE lt.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE type = 'R' AND name IS NOT NULL) 
AND sp.type != 'R';

REVERT;
```

**Result**

```
name
DOMAIN\a-rvertongen
DOMAIN\SERVER_RO
DOMAIN\SERVER_sysadmin
BUILTIN\Administrators
```

---

> Also, what happens if multiple groups are added as sql-server logins,
>   and I'm a member of them all, and then I login with integrated
>   security.Which login will it take ?

**Permissions for multiple AD groups**

You will be granted the `GRANT` / `DENY` rights of each  `AD Group`. 
`DENY` take precedence over `GRANT` permissions.

A more thorough write up in a previous answer by  [@Max Vernon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon) can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131137/effective-sql-server-permissions-when-user-is-in-several-ad-groups).

Comment: Yea, aggregation of the rights, that hopefully, but the language seems to be taken from the first :) Is there a way to get this with a function ? I need the name in a trigger.

Comment: @Quandary added a DMV that you can use

Comment: OK thank you very much, that works.

Comment: Yep. Just one small correction: the correct WHERE-clause is: WHERE lt.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE type = 'R'  AND name IS NOT NULL) 
AND lt.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals WHERE type = 'R' AND name IS NOT NULL )

Comment: @Quandary great, thanks for pointing that out! Edited